# How can I write a cuda kernel for this function?

Tags: c, cuda, linear-algebra, hpc

I have a kernel in C that I would like to covert to a cuda kernel. However, I’m having a trouble with writing the kernel for this function as it consists of multiple nested loops. My approach is to separate this function into three different kernel, one for each operation.
This is the original function:

```
void  kernel(int N, double B[N][N]) {

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
          B[i][j] = B[i][j] - (B[i][k] * B[k][j]);
      }
       B[i][j] = B[i][j] / B[j][j];
    }
    for (int j = i; j < N; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
         B[i][j] = B[i][j] - (B[i][k] * B[k][j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my attempt at converting it to 3 different kernels:

```
__global__ void kernal_1(int N, double* B){

 int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
 int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
 int k;

    if (i < N && j<i) {
        for (k = 0; k < j; k++) {
             B[i][j] = B[i][j] - (B[i][k] * B[k][j]);
            } 
    }

}

__global__ void  kernal_2(int N, double* B){

 int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
 int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (i < N && j<i) {
      B[i][j] = B[i][j] / B[j][j];

    }

}


__global__ void kernal_3(int N, double* B){

int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
int k;

    if (i < N && j<=i) {
    for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
         B[i][j] = B[i][j] - (B[i][k] * B[k][j]);
        }    
       
}}
```

I know my attempt is wrong as I don’t get the correct result. Any advice or suggestion? This is for LU decomposition by the way. I've seen people do it differently where the outer i loop is not implemented in the kernel, instead it is used in the main function where it calls the kernels, the kernels would have 2 loops in each case

Edit: Included memory access pattern

Comment: You don't show any relevant parts of your code such as the memory access pattern

Comment: In-place changes like this cannot possibly work in parallel since one thread may access an element from `B` that another thread is changing out-of-order. LU decompositions are non-trivial problems for GPUs with plenty of research papers. You sure you want to tackle the problem manually instead of using [CuSolver](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#cusolverdnxgetrf)?

Comment: To maintain the sequence of operations, I think you need to fix i in your kernels, and run them each N times for different i. You should also look up branchless coding as if statements in GPU kernels are a massive performance killer. Also are the conditional statements in loops. This is not going to an easy thing to run efficiently on a GPU. It could be much slower than your single-threaded CPU function. You should give us some idea how big N is typically. I would consider other options like SIMD and pthreads too. I don't understand the downvotes.

Answer (score -3):

First answer is, you could try dynamic parallelism in CUDA, you can search relavant content in CUDA prgoramming guide on google. (but maybe too hard for a CUDA beginner)

Second idea is, no need to split them into three kernels, just use one kernel, because different kernels will transfer data from global to register and to global and to register, which is definitely very very slow. Using CUDA is just like one layer of for, so you just need to consider how to allocate the task to all threads to contents below:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
         // operation 1 
      }
      //operation 2
    }
    for (int j = i; j < N; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        // operation 3 
      }
    }
```

If the first iterator, "i = 0; i < N; i++" is large enough to fill the GPU, just use for loop(for j and k) within the kernel, it is OK. What you should do is fully use GPU's capability. How to know whether N is large enough? So you firstly write a kernel, and use this [occupancy calculator](https://xmartlabs.github.io/cuda-calculator/) (use nsight compute to find your shared memory and register value) to find out warp occupancy, and get how much block can be active in one SM, and times the total SM number you have. Then you get it.